# iOS Custom framework linker error

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I want to make a framework from C++ classes and one Objective-C class. The Objective-C class  inherits from a class which is located in an third-party framework.

I'm checking with `#if  __has_include(<Foo1/Foo1.h>)` if the framework - especially the class - is already located in the project.

I´m able to build the framework, but when I including it, the build fails with the following error message:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FOO2", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

How can I solve this issue? Or is there an better way?

Answer (score 0):

This is a random guess but try to add ld linker flag -all_load (Other linker flags section)